# conditional compilation question

Tags: c#, .net

I have two projects A and B. A depends on B. I would like the following to happen

If B define a conditional compilation symbol, I would like A also define it automatically. Can I achieve this?

Comment: I dont think this is possible. Perhaps someone knows some MSBuild magic to perform this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, basically. Compilation symbols are applied on a per-project basis in the project settings, and on a per-file basis depending on `#define` pragmas. There's no way of making the project you're compiling against determine your compilation symbols - they vanish after compilation, effectively.

It would be simplest to create appropriate *solution-wide* configurations, and project configurations within them which define the appropriate symbols.

Comment: Jon, Coudl you please provide more details about "create  appropriate solution-wide configurations"?

Comment: @user496949: I mean you go into Configuration Manager and create a new configuration, agreeing to create new project configurations as well. Then tinker with each project configuration to define the right preprocessor symbols.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of project files,

- Use custom MSBuild script
- Or write a "project file generator" that will create all your project files for you (they are just XML after all)

(It is a real pity you can't selet more then one project file then "multi edit" them)